# Compatibility of Presto and Hadoop for running on Graviton2 instances

Tags: hadoop, presto, aws-graviton

Which Presto version provides compatibility with the Graviton Processor? Does Presto have a dependency on Hadoop? If it does, does Presto require a specific compatible version of Hadoop to run on the Graviton Processor, and if so, which Hadoop version is compatible with Presto in this context?

I have researched but could not find any details specific to this.

Answer (score 1):

Presto can run independently of Hadoop clusters.
But specifically on arm64 processors, deployment issues exist. Please refer [this github link](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/19981).

You need the latest version of Hadoop.

Comment: Can you please also answer this question - "Which Presto version provides compatibility with the Graviton Processor"?